# macro_rules presume type about arguments

Tags: rust, rust-macros

tl;dr I *think* I want a macro declaration to infer type (how do I create this macro?)

This macro fails to compile ([rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a0f9f5ee4f23e2d354ec3ab0ea5071a6))

```rust
macro_rules! debug_assert_none {
    ($($arg:tt),+) => {
        $(
            if cfg!(debug_assertions) {
                match $arg {
                    None => {}
                    Some(..) => panic!("not None")
                }
            }
        )+
    };
}

#[test]
fn test_debug_assert_none() {
    debug_assert_none!(None);
    debug_assert_none!(None, None);
}
```

Fails with error

```text
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/lib.rs:15:24
   |
15 |     debug_assert_none!(None);
   |                        ^^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `T` declared on the enum `Option`
   |
help: consider specifying the generic argument
   |
15 |     debug_assert_none!(None::<T>);
   |                            +++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0282`.
```

How do I satisfy the required type declaration for a presumed `Option`?
Or is there some other problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

How is the compiler supposed to know the size it has to reserve for a bare `None`? It can't because it could hold any other type. As soon as you use your macro in a real world scenario, the type should be possible to infer, but if you want to pass in a bare `None`, you can always specify it explicitly by just giving it a type; usually one uses unit `()` for unused parameters.

```rust
debug_assert_none!(None::<()>);
```

Of course, you could also change your macro to help type inference but that would restrict the macro to work only with values of that one type:

```rust
macro_rules! debug_assert_none {
    ($($arg:tt),+) => {
        $(
            if cfg!(debug_assertions) {
                let x: &Option<()> = &$arg;
                match $arg {
                    None => {}
                    Some(..) => panic!("not None")
                }
            }
        )+
    };
}
```

Comment: `let` imposes some constraints on temporaries. Better to use `match $arg { None::<()> => ... }`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I can't think of any constraints this `let` imposes which aren't desired (`T` of the `Option`) or don't have to hold true anyways can you elaborate?

Comment: Well, not in case of `Option<()>`, but in other cases [yes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=593e3424ec7f3110f6e9ebc18ec09d0c).